# HQL ingoring transaction

Tags: spring, hibernate, transactions, hql

im building an Spring 4 + Hibernate 4 app. My config is this:

```
@Bean
public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
    sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(packagesDaoAnotaciones);
    sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
    return sessionFactory;
}

@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    // Configuración del DataSource por el Servidor.
    final JndiDataSourceLookup dsLookup = new JndiDataSourceLookup();
    dsLookup.setResourceRef(true);
    DataSource dataSource = dsLookup.getDataSource(environment.getRequiredProperty("jndi.datasource"));
    return dataSource;
}

private Properties hibernateProperties() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("hibernate.dialect", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
    properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
    properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.format_sql"));
    properties.put("hibernate.generate_statistics", "true");

    return properties;
}

@Bean
@Autowired
public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory s) {
    HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
    txManager.setSessionFactory(s);
    return txManager;
}
```

I have a Service with this method:

```
@Override
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, rollbackFor = Exception.class)
public void processThis() throws Exception {
    List<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();
    myList.add("1234567890");

    myDao.update(myList,'01', "1234567890");

    LOGGER.info("buahhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh");
}
```

The Dao executes an HQL query like this:

```
    @Override
public int update(List<String> data, String data1, String data2) {
    StringBuffer hql = new StringBuffer();
    hql.append("UPDATE MyTablenp SET np.field1 = :d1, field2= sysdate, field3= :d2, field4= sysdate, field5= null,field6= null    WHERE np.data IN (:num)");

    this.getSession().getTransaction().isActive();
    Query query = this.getSession().createQuery(hql.toString());
    query.setParameterList("num", data);
    query.setParameter("d1", data1);
    query.setParameter("d2", data2);

    return query.executeUpdate();
}
```

When i execute this, i can see the data modified in the BBDD just after dao method ends, but the service method didnt finish yet, so its commiting the HQL without finish the transaction method. Do anyone knows how to avoid that commit and commit only when service method ends?

Comment: Why do you want to do that ?

Comment: This process is transactional, so that update cannot be commited until service method is finished correctly. After this update the methof continues doing a lot of things in the BBDD so all must be commited or rollback as a transaction. If the update commits by itself the process will do wrong things.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the existing session opened by hibernate at the start of the annotated method `proccessThis()`.
In your DAO do the following:

Remove this: `this.getSession().getTransaction().isActive();`

and instead get current session from the session factory(assuming you have extended `HibernateDaoSupport`):

```
Session session = this.getHibernateTemplate().getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
```